# Queryparams to associative array

Tags: javascript, parameters, uri

I would like to make query params to an associative array.

So, for instance:

http://localhost:8000/products?&size=2&type=all&nice&categories=a%20%b%20&m=true

should be:

```js
{
  size: '2',
  type: 'all',
  nice: undefined,
  categories: ['a', 'b', 'c'],
  m: 'true'
}
```

My approach:

```js
const newURI = new URL('http://localhost:8000/products?&size=2&type=all&nice&categories=a%20%b%20&m=true');
const queryParams = new URLSearchParams(newURI.search);

const associativeObj = { ...Array.from(queryParams).map(el => {
    el[0]: el[1]
  })
}
```

Can someone help ?

Comment: param `categories` dont have `c`

Comment: `Object.fromEntries(queryParams)` should do the trick.